# Asp.Net Core project gives "No webpage was found" only when executed with IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have asp.net core project and when I execute it under Visual Studio 2017 as project, everything works just fine. But when I switch to run IIS Express (with exactly the same ports; also under VS2017), the same page which was reachable before now gives me error "No webpage was found". I don't see any difference in settings, so what I should set additionally to make it work in IIS Express "mode" as well?

For now I use just `http` (i.e. no `https`) just to make sure some kind SSL problem is not involved here.

*I don't understand "too broad" comment, so let me reiterate. I have VS 2017 asp.net core project, with two profiles, project and IIS, both settings look the same. When I launch project in IIS Express (under VS2017) it does not work, page not found, when I launch project in project mode, the same page is loaded. I am looking for the cause of this difference.*

Answer (score 0):

do you tryed use staticfiles?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Comment: Suggest explain more.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help (i.e. I don't see any effect this way, or another).